# mock functions don't work in .test files after adding setupFilesAfterEnv

Tags: node.js, typescript, jestjs, ts-jest

After adding **setupFilesAfterEnv** in the jest.config.js like that:

```js
module.exports = {
    preset: 'ts-jest',
    testEnvironment: 'node',

    setupFilesAfterEnv: ["./test/setupAfterEnv.ts"]  
}
```

the mock functions don't work anymore in the `.test.ts` files but works in the file that was written inside the setupFilesAfterEnv like `./test/setupAfterEnv.ts`

mock function example(the `.test.ts` file and `setupAfterEnv.ts` in the same director):

```js
jest.mock("../src/service/sendEmail.ts", () => ({
    send: () => {
        return "MOCK sendEmail sent"
    }
}));
```

- I don't get any errors, and the other function that should be mocked runs. When I write wrong path in the mock function, I get the error `can't find module`. So it looks it find the function that should be mocked but doesn't run the mock function and run the other function instead
- And if I commented the **setupFilesAfterEnv** config in `jest.config.js`  it works again.

Comment: What does "don't work" mean? What exactly is the behaviour in both cases?

Comment: I don't get any errors, and the other function that should be mocked runs. When I write wrong path in the mock function, I get error `can't find module`. So it looks it find the function that should be mocked but doesn't run the mock function and run the other function instead. @EstusFlask

Comment: *and the other function that should be mocked runs* - which one? From another module? Can you provide https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve that can reproduce the problem? I'm unaware of any circumstances under which this could happen.

Comment: I'm having the same issue right now

Comment: @SethCaldwell  I noticed it doesn't work with `setupFilesAfterEnv `.  better to import the mock file at the beginning of your ts test file like 
`import './mocks';` or create __mocks__  directory as shown in jest docs [here](https://jestjs.io/docs/manual-mocks)

Comment: still no dice. I created the manual mocks, but 
expect(MockedClass.somefunction).toHaveBeenCalledWith(something); it will throw 'Matcher error: received value must be a mock or spy function.' as MockedClass.somefunction is the actual real class function, not a mocked version.

Comment: oh and to clarify further, if I do have jest.mock('somePath/someClass'); inside the setupFilesAfterEnv file itself, it works perfectly.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Documentation states

```
Warning: Importing a module in a setup file
(as specified by setupTestFrameworkScriptFile)
will prevent mocking for the module in question, 
as well as all the modules that it imports.
```

If you have any imports/requires in your ./test/setupAfterEnv.ts, they likely imported other files, and anything chain imported in that process will not be able to be mock('../somemodule'); within tests.

I'm not sure why this restriction is in place; if you call the mock('../somemodule') within the setupAfterEnv.ts file itself, it will be mocked later within your tests. But I consider that bad, as only some tests may want to mock some modules, and others expect them not to be mocked. A pity. In my case, I wanted to import a typeorm library and connect to the database. But the class that creates this connection imports all our entities and all the entity classes import other classes which import other classes etc etc... so nothing becomes mockable. Simply unusable because of this restriction.

Comment: I saw this comment after 16 hours of struggling. Jest is such a random piece of software.